# How can I avoid memory leaks coming from std::list and std::vector

Tags: c++, valgrind, stdvector, stdlist

I keep fighting memory leaks on a project coded by a former colleague. Valgrind doesn't seem to like std::vector and std::list resize. For example, if I take this method:

```
void BaseImage::setImageSize(unsigned short width, unsigned short height, unsigned short nbBytePerPixel, const boost::posix_time::ptime& timestamp)
{
    m_timestamp = timestamp;
    bool change = m_width!=width || m_height!=height || m_bytesByPixel!=nbBytePerPixel;
    if(change)
    {
        m_width = width;
        m_height = height;
        m_bytesByPixel = nbBytePerPixel;
        m_stride = m_width * m_bytesByPixel;
        if( m_bufferSize < (m_width * m_height * m_bytesByPixel) + m_headerSize)
        {
            m_bufferSize = m_width * m_height * m_bytesByPixel;
            if (m_data.size()!=(m_headerSize + m_bufferSize))
                m_data.resize(m_headerSize + m_bufferSize);
        }
    }
}
```

With:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime m_timestamp;
unsigned short m_width;
unsigned short m_height;
unsigned short m_bytesByPixel;
unsigned int m_stride;
unsigned int m_bufferSize;
unsigned short m_headerSize;
std::vector<unsigned char> m_data;
```

I get the following leak in my valgrind logfile:

```
==10093== 614,412 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 10,043 of 10,050
==10093==    at 0x4C337B3: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:422)
==10093==    by 0x1B9C91: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned char>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:111)
==10093==    by 0x1B9ACF: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<unsigned char> >::allocate(std::allocator<unsigned char>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
==10093==    by 0x1B991D: std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:172)
==10093==    by 0x1B934B: std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_default_append(unsigned long) (vector.tcc:571)
==10093==    by 0x1B8E9C: std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::resize(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:692)
==10093==    by 0x1B716C: xawcore::BaseImage::setImageSize(unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short, boost::posix_time::ptime const&) (baseimage.cpp:262)
==10093==    by 0x1B6FBD: xawcore::BaseImage::setImageSize(unsigned short, unsigned short, xawcore::PixelType, boost::posix_time::ptime const&) (baseimage.cpp:241)
==10093==    by 0x1B6F1E: xawcore::BaseImage::setImageSize(unsigned short, unsigned short, xawcore::PixelType, xawcore::StreamType, boost::posix_time::ptime const&) (baseimage.cpp:229)
==10093==    by 0x1B6ECE: xawcore::BaseImage::setImageSize(unsigned short, unsigned short, xawcore::PixelType, xawcore::StreamType, bool, boost::posix_time::ptime const&) (baseimage.cpp:223)
==10093==    by 0x21112D: xawcore::OpenNI2Device::acquisition(bool) (openni2device.cpp:314)
==10093==    by 0x218219: xawcore::OnlineStream::acquisitionThread(bool) [clone ._omp_fn.0] (onlinestream.cpp:127)
```

I also have a similar error when resize is used on a std::list.
Is it a false positive? If not, should I use something else than resize or do some steps before using it?

Comment: Your code doesn't show anything using `xawcore`, so this isn't a [mcve].  In my experience though, `valgrind` false positives are pretty rare.

Comment: I'd put my hand into fire that it isn't `std::vector` that's leaking memory – rather some other object with an embedded `std::vector` member.

Comment: At a glance, your resizing for `m_bufferSize` looks weird. You check if it's smaller than `m_width * m_height * m_bytesPerPixel + m_headerSize`, and then if it is, you set it to... Something that's still smaller than `m_width * m_height * m_bytesPerPixel + m_headerSize`?

Comment: Is there anywhere where you `memcpy` (or similar) a `BaseImage`?

Comment: What, exactly, in the shown backtrace you believe is the conclusive proof that memory is being leaked from `std::list` or `std::vector`? Spoiler alert: there is no proof. The leak can be coming from anywhere in the backtrace, and the chances of memory leaking bugs in the C++ library are far less likely than a memory leak in the other class that shows up in the backtrace.

Comment: @NathanPierson Not really. Buffer size is the size of the image data without the header, but the data vector includes this one. Looks to me, though, as if the header size rather should be a constant than a member (unless the type should cover different image formats).

Comment: If the idea is that buffer size is supposed to be "image data without the header" and the vector size is supposed to be "buffer size plus header size", why compare buffer size to "buffer size plus header size" at all?

Comment: I suspect that `xawcore::OpenNI2Device::acquisition(bool)` creates `xawcore::BaseImage`s that never get properly destroyed and deallocated.

Comment: @NathanPierson Agree in that I'd do the calculations differently as well – though the result wouldn't change. Code looks rather like someone tried to spare intermediate variables and code lines in favour of re-calculating the same value again and again. Not a good style, I'd say, still it should yield the desired result.

Comment: What if `m_bufferSize` is currently 100, `m_headerSize` is currently 10, and the implied newly-desired buffer size is 95? We'll enter the `if`, shrink `m_bufferSize`, and then shrink `m_data` from 110 elements to 105 elements. I assumed the goal was to ensure that `m_bufferSize` is a ratchet that increases but never goes back down.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh [@*&%+!] – have been inattendent – *`reserve`* doesn't exist, of course…

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I thought it came from resize because of the line "==10093==    by 0x1B8E9C: std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::resize(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:692)". I used Valgrind for the first time last week, so I'm not sure how to interpret some messages. Should I clear the vector before doing a resize? Create a new one to replace the previous one? I'm quite lost on how to properly use resize here, or what I could do before using it and not have these memory leaks, this is why I'm asking.

Comment: It is true that some class in the code ended up `resize`()ing a vector. But something in the code forgot to delete the object that contained the vector. This leaked all memory, including the memory allocated by `resize()`. But it is not `resize()` that leaked anything. It is whatever code is responsible for destroying the vector itself that's broken. `valgrind` is correctly told you that memory allocated by `resize` was not deleted. But that's not `resize()`'s fault. If your car catches on fire it's not your fault that you put gasoline into it, in the first place.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay, I get it. I was confused because of the Valgrind line where resize was mentioned. Some of the memory leaks I encountered came from missing destructors in some of my coworkers' classes, that's probably the case here too, I guess.

Comment: @NathanPierson yes, it's more likely an error. From the rest of the code, I think it's supposed to be "m_bufferSize < m_width * m_height * m_bytesByPixel" instead. I will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind *does not* tell you that `resize` did something funny.

It tells you that you forgot to deallocate some memory, and gives you an idea on who allocated them, so you can find the responsible to free them.

So who *should* free them?  Ah, that would be the `vector`.  And who should free the `vector`?  Ah, that would be your object.  And who should free your object?  That, only you can tell.

Comment: Yes, seems like it also from the comments above. I got confused because line about resize in Valgrind, but it's more likely caused a missing destructor again (had to add several previously, to fix others memory leaks). Thanks

Comment: Properly interpreting tool output is hard and confusing at first.  It's worth the effort, though, to take the time to learn it.  It gives you many chances to help others, and doing so get stackoverflow rep ;).

Comment: I still have a lot to learn, but I hope I will be able to help people at some point

Comment: "missing destructor again...": it may surprise you, but there is a chance that you don't need to write any destructors if you're designing it right.  Do read up on "the rule of zero", e.g., https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/04/23/the-rule-of-zero-zero-constructor-zero-calorie/